# how to change master page label's text after a button click on child page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using shopping cart icon showing number of products in cart. but when i add item to cart shopping is not updated.so i want to know if there is any method to change master page label's text after a button click on child page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to provide a public property in your `MasterPage` that you can use to set/get the Label's Text.

in your Master(assuming it's type is called `SiteMaster`):

```
public String ShoppingCartNumber{ 
    get{ return LblShoppingCart.Text; }
    set{ LblShoppingCart.Text = value; }
}
```

In your button's click event handler:

```
SiteMaster master = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;
master.ShoppingCartNumber = "1234";
```

This approach is straight-forward, less prone to errors and easily readable. You could even change the control in your master without needing to change the pages (f.e. if you want to replace the Label with a TextBox).

Comment: i am unable to get master's public property because i have cast page.master in to my specific master. so how can i get that property or i have to find control(label) and set the value of that label.

Comment: @user1372444: Have you implemented that property in your master at all as shown above? If so, what error do you see when you try to access it via `((YourMasterType)Page.Master).ShoppingCartNumber` from the button-click in the content page?

Comment: sorry tim...i was using another master instead of original one.

Comment: Then the best would be to pass it from master to master. So the page accesses a property from it's direct master that links to a property in it's parent master which references the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Label mpLabel = (Label) Master.FindControl("masterPageLabel");
if(mpLabel != null)
{
    Label1.Text = "Master page label = " + mpLabel.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add in your `masterpage.cs` file:

```
public Label lbl
    {
        get { return YourLabelId; }
        set { YourLabelId= value; }
    }
```

Add this in your content page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/YourMasterPageName.Master" %>
```

Then access in content page in your button click event:

```
string name = Master.lbl.text;
```